# Highcharts: Rotate VU dials

Tags: highcharts

I've been trying to rotate highcharts VU dials (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-vu-meter).  I'm trying to make them vertical with the VU labels centered and horizontal.  Does anyone know if there is a property for this?

Comment: Could you attach any mockup of your idea?

Answer (score 0):

With a guage chart (VU dial), adjust the angles of the pane:

```
    pane: [{
        startAngle: 0, // 12 o'clock
        endAngle: 180, // to 6 o'clock
        background: null
    }],
```

Horizontal labels can be obtained by getting rid of the `rotation` option on the labels:

```
   labels: {
       distance: 20
   },
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgg74q4k/).

[image]